# AS400 database - Error - PWS9801 - Function rejected by user exit program

Tags: vba, ibm-midrange

I am trying to read data from AS400 database on a remote machine using ODBC driver and VBA.
I could successfully establish the connection, but none of the queries return data. All the queries run into the error "[IBM] [System i Access ODBC Driver] [DB2 for i5/OS] PWS9801 - Function rejected by user exit program in library SQLSECR0 QSYSMCD". Please help me...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a security program (called an exit program) on the IBM i side which is denying you access.  You need to get clearance from the IBM administrators.